# Android record square Video

Tags: android, video

I'm currently trying to record a video with the MediaRecorder and a Camera. But for my Application, I need to record a video in square-format, like Instagram does with Pictures, to be independet of device orientation.

Is there any way to automatically crop and preview a video in a square-resoultion (f.i. 800x800) or do I have to crop the video manually (I have FFMPEG available on the Android-Device)?

Comment: I have the same issue, i have to record as a square, when I'm in portrait mode, if you find something, please let me know. I will do the same

Comment: Hey, guys, aren't you both interviewing for a work in smrtlabs? (= I have same task

Comment: This question might be outdated in the meantime, but has this ever been solved in an elegant way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never found a solution.

Comment: To get a square video, I've had to create a box overlay on a camera surface view, measure the position and size against the device screen size, then use ffmpeg to crop the video using the box overlay coords.

Comment: try this its best square camera for me https://github.com/CrazyOrr/FFmpegRecorder

Answer (score 0):

Using an ImageView, I can set a square height and width (say 100dip x 100dip). Then using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` gives me an image which is cropped to square regardless of aspect ratio.